# ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement

Tags: ms-access, odbc

I took the path straight from the connection string that it gave me when i created the odbc connection to my database. Table1 is my table and the Database is called VideoGameDatabase.

```
Dim strPath6 As String = "Driver={Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)};dbq=C:\USERS\KIRITO\DESKTOP\VideoGameDatabase.mdb;defaultdir=C:\USERS\KIRITO\DESKTOP;driverid=25;fil=MS Access;filedsn=C:\Users\Kirito\Desktop\VideoGameDatabase.dsn;maxbuffersize=2048;maxscanrows=8;pagetimeout=5;safetransactions=0;threads=3;uid=admin;usercommitsync=Yes"
    Dim Connection2 As New System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection(strPath6)
    Connection2.Open()
    Dim cmd As OdbcCommand = New OdbcCommand("INSERT INTO Table1 " & _
       "(Slot, Health, Gold, Level, Strength, Vitality, Agility, XP) " & _
       "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", Connection2)

    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Slot", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = 1
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Health", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Battle.lblPlayerHealth.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Gold", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblMoney.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Level", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblLevel.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Strength", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblStrength.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Vitality", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblVitality.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Agility", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Stats.lblAgility.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@XP", OdbcType.VarChar, 255).Value = Inventory.lblXP.Text
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Connection2.Close()
```

Comment: According to the Microsoft support document [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-e33eb3a9-8baa-4335-9f57-da237c63eabe?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US#__toc272229040), `LEVEL` appears to be a reserved word in Access SQL. Try enclosing it in [square brackets] in your CommandText.